# Refresh Azure Storage Account Key Periodically using C# SDK

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

For security purpose I want refresh my storage account key every month. I gone through Azure Storage SDK but couldn’t find any specific way to do so.

Is there any nuget/sdk available for that? I am good with powershell script as well but should be able to execute it through some scheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Azure Management SDK with an App Registration to do this.

Here's exactly the steps you need to take to do it:

**1.** Go to the Azure portal App Registration here: https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/RegisteredApps

**2.** Register a new APP by clicking New Registration:

[image]

**3.** Type any name for your App and Register it

**4.** Create a new secret for your app here:
[image]

**5.** Copy the secret, we'll use it later (do not share or store in source control!)

**6.** On the App Registration page make a copy of the CLIENT ID and the Tenant ID as shown here:
[image]

**7.** Go to the subscriptions on the portal and copy your subscription id

**8.** Now go to the blob account you want to reset the keys for and on Overview click JSON View and copy the **Resource ID**:

[image]
[image]

**8b.** Give access to your new app to the blob storage acccount, you can do this by going to Access control (IAM) on the blob storage account and adding a new role assignment.

**9.** On your project install the following nuget packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage" Version="22.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent" Version="1.37.1" />
```

Note you can use higher versions if available.

**10.** Now you can use this code to reset the keys:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core;

namespace AzureMng
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var creds = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(
                "[ENTER CLIENT-ID]", 
                "[ENTER SECRET]",  
                "[ENTER TENANT ID", 
                AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
            var client = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure.Configure()
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                .Authenticate(creds)
                .WithSubscription("[ENTER YOUR SubscriptionID]");
            
            var account = client.StorageAccounts.GetById(
                "");
            var keys = await account.RegenerateKeyAsync("key1");
            Console.WriteLine(keys.FirstOrDefault().Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can change both keys or a single key. You can also copy the generated keys.